# Javascript callback after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, callback

Hi I would like to ask about: Is there a way to call function which been returned in json object with parameters? For example I have ajax when is success I return a json object in that object I've got `{"callback":{"func":"doAlert","param":"param1"}}` and

```
sucsess:function(data){
 data.callback.func(data.callback.param);
}
```

I have

```
var doAlert=function(param){
alert(param);
}
```

And I get that, my function is not defined.

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(data);` in `success:` parameter of Jquery Ajax.
And Whats the response can you alert it or log it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment, again this message TypeError: data.callback.func is not a function

Comment: Can you alert the data(The response of Ajax Request) or log it to see what is it actually ?

Comment: Where is the `doAlert` function defined ?

Comment: Try using `window[data.callback.func](data.callback.param)`, assuming `doAlert` is in the global scope. Otherwise replace `window`  with the corresponding scope.

Comment: {"callback":{"func":"doAlert","param":"param1"}}
after json:parser
functions.js (line 27)
Object { callback={...}}
functions.js (line 29)
function name doAlert
functions.js (line 30)
function param: param1

Comment: With window[data.callback.func] is working, but what means this I have to declared the function inside the success :?

Comment: The problem is that `data.callback.func` only contains the string `"doAlert"`, not the reference to the function. But if it is in the global scope, you can get that reference by accessing it through its name, hence `window[data.callback.func]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use eval. Just do

```
window[data.callback.func](data.callback.param);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. you have to use eval to evaluates the expression:

```
eval(data.callback.func)(data.callback.param);
```

Comment: `eval` is evil and you most certainly don't *have* to use it.

Comment: but it's answer to his question. so why vote down? Maybe it's not the best answer and it's not will accept. but it's not wrong proffesor.

Comment: Because it is not a good answer. If `eval` can be avoided, it should be avoided. And "have to" is just plain wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use EVAL to convert the function name in JSON from string to function

```
var funcevaluated=eval(data.callback.func);
funcevaluated(data.callback.param);
```

Working example in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghjZu/

Comment: No, you don't *need* to use `eval`.